# error: variable has incomplete type 'introstructions' can't understand

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
struct calcvaribles;
{
int a;
int b;
int sum;
};
struct introstructions;
{
char ab[35];
string ac;
};
introstructions outline;
outline.ab = "welcome to my calculator program!";
outline.ac = "please enter any [One] number in the 
terminal";
return 0;
}
```

Error message:

aggregate main()::introstructions outline had incomplete type and cannot be defined

Introstructions outline.

Comment: I think you mean C++ for the tag, not CSS

Comment: You trailing semi colon after 'struct introstructions;' is wrong

Comment: Well I guess i should be more attentive to my own notes lol.

Answer (score 1):

- Why are you declaring `struct`s inside `main`? Just move them into
  global scope.
- You cannot assign a string literal to a `char` array as you do here: `outline.ab = "welcome to my calculator program!";`. Instead, use a `const char*` or, better yet, as you showed below the `char` array declaration, `std::string`, but don't forget to `#include <string>`.

The problem in your code is that you include a `;` after the `struct` name:

```cpp
    struct calcvaribles;
    struct introstructions;
```

The following should work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    struct calcvaribles {
        int a;
        int b;
        int sum;
    };

    struct introstructions {
        string ab;
        string ac;
    };

    introstructions outline;

    outline.ab = "welcome to my calculator program!";
    outline.ac = "please enter any [One] number in the terminal";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation the C++ language does not help you since the compiler interprets the code in a completely different way than you expect it.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
struct calcvaribles;
```

Because of the semicolon at the end of the above line, the compiler reads this as:

There is a struct called `calcvaribles`. It's not clear at this point which fields the struct has, that's to be defined elsewhere. In any case, the struct's name is already known, and if you declare a variable of type *pointer to that struct*, that's allowed from no on.

```
{
```

This opening brace means:

A new scope starts here. Any variable that is declared in this scope will only be available until the corresponding `}`.

```
int a;
int b;
int sum;
```

Instead of being struct fields (what you intended), these are declarations of normal variables. These variables don't do anything, they have no values assigned and their values are not read at all. In summary, these three lines are a big "do nothing" block.

```
};
```

The scope ends here. From no on, the variables `a`, `b` and `sum` are no more.

The semicolon is useless as well. It's an empty statement. Allowed but useless.

```
struct introstructions;
{
char ab[35];
string ac;
};
introstructions outline;
outline.ab = "welcome to my calculator program!";
outline.ac = "please enter any [One] number in the 
terminal";
return 0;
}
```

The same happens with the `introstructions` type.

Had you written the `struct` definitions outside of the `main` function, the compiler would have given you a "syntax error" message. Maybe you did that first, and to fix the error message, you moved everything into the main function.

It's unfortunate that only because of these trailing semicolons, the code you wrote still compiled but means something entirely different. But there's no workaround for that.